Trying to get user timeline on Twitter using Python (Tweepy), keep getting error 453
I want to extract the timeline from a specifc user (Last 2 Years), using code below, but keep getting errror '403 Forbidden
When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal'
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='@$@#$@$',
    consumer_key='@$@#$@$',
    consumer_secret='@$@#$@$',
    access_token='2863466581-@$@#$@$',
    access_token_secret='@$@#$@$'
)
user = client.get_user(username='nytimes')

paginator = tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets, id=user.data.id, max_results=2)

for tweet in paginator.flatten(limit=3200):
    print(tweet)

Want to extract last 2 year of user timeline from twitter API;

That error message is telling your pretty much everything you need to know. Also 453 != 403.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

"Want to extract last 2 year of user timeline from twitter API;" Then you need to subscribe to one of the paid for access tiers at X. (Maybe "Pro" that's $5000/month.)
